# How to deal with console.log in Ionic 4 when preparing for release on iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

What is the best practice (in relation to security and performance) to handle console.log(s) during the release stage of an iOS app build with Ionic4?

Will `ionic cordova build ios --prod` disable logs. Hence, no insights about the iOS app can be revealed and no performance will be wasted on logging?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely remove console.log(), you can overwrite this function in main.ts file. this is an efficient way fo doing it.

```
if (window) {
   window.console.log = function () { };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Production ios and android builds removed debugging capabilities, no will be able to see these/access them. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/remove-console-logs-release/76590 
though there not technically removed so I imagen it would run faster if you comment them.

Comment: I have seen this post before but I could not infer the conclusion you have made especially that "Production ios and android builds removed debugging capabilities".